# preparing cursor in mysql but not working,

Tags: mysql

i used the below command to prepare the cursor in MySQL but getting an error. where I am wrong and what needs to rectify?

```
delimiter &&

create procedure cursor_table()

begin

declare firstname varchar(100);

declare cl int default 0;

Declare cursor_2 cursor for select s_fname from student_datasets limit 3;

open cursor_2;

repeat

fetch cursor_2 into firstname;

set cl=cl+1;

until cl=5

end repeat;

select firstname;

close cursor_2;

end &&
```

getting error as 1064

i am a beginner in mysql and trying to prepare cursor but not working and getting error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error please add full error message. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea915ac26b5aae3aa497f0ee11b01561 note - it's a feature of the fiddle that you don't have to set delimiters and perhaps you don't need to either.

Comment: error comes at after call procedure as below:Error Code: 1329. No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed

Comment: why this comes as in student_dataets data avaiable;

Comment: Please add sample data as text.

Answer (score 0):

Code: 1329. No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed  - you are selecting 3 into cursor but looping 5 times error is thrown on fetch at loop 4. Either fix your code so that you loop for as many records as you select or as is more conventional use a continuation handler as described with examples in the manual. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html Note the code as written can only output the last s_fname selected perhaps the select should be inside the loop

Comment: as per your guidance i change the code as below and got only one name in result.CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `cursor_table`()
begin
declare firstname varchar(100);
declare cl int default 0;
declare lst varchar(100);
Declare cursor_2 cursor for select s_fname from student_datasets;
open cursor_2;
repeat 
fetch cursor_2 into firstname;
set lst=concat(firstname,",",firstname);
set cl=cl+1;
until cl=5
end repeat;
select lst;
close cursor_2;
end

Comment: Kinldy help me what changes need to to be do in code to get all five names from tables as i apply loop .

Comment: You should reread the answer.